# Join on non-unique second id - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to join a dictionary to another dictionary. I have two keys; one that is unique and another which is not unique. I want to join information on the non-unique key and leave all information as it is one the unique key, i.e. the number of unique id's has to stay the same.

Any ideas to how I can achieve this?

This is the first dictionary:

```
    names = [
    {'id': '1', 'name': 'Peter', 'category_id': '25'}, 
    {'id': '2', 'name': 'Jim', 'category_id': '20'}, 
    {'id': '3', 'name': 'Toni', 'category_id': '20'}
]
```

This is the second dictionary:

```
categories = [
    {'category_id': '25', 'level': 'advanced'}, 
    {'category_id': '20', 'level': 'beginner'}
]
```

And this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
all = [
    {'id': '1', 'name': 'Peter', 'category_id': '25', 'level': 'advanced'}, 
    {'id': '2', 'name': 'Jim', 'category_id': '20', 'level': 'beginner'}, 
    {'id': '3', 'name': 'Toni', 'category_id': '20', 'level': 'beginner'}
]
```

EDIT:

```
names = [
    {'id': '1', 'name': 'Peter', 'category_id': '25'}, 
    {'id': '2', 'name': 'Jim', 'category_id': '20'}, 
    {'id': '3', 'name': 'Toni', 'category_id': '20'}
]

categories = [
    {'category_id': '25', 'level': 'advanced'}, 
    {'category_id': '20', 'level': 'beginner'}
]

def merge_lists(l1, l2, key):
    merged = {}
    for item in l1+l2:
        if item[key] in merged:
            merged[item[key]].update(item)
        else:
            merged[item[key]] = item
    return merged.values()

courses = merge_lists(names, categories, 'category_id')
print(courses)
```

gives:

```
([{'id': '1', 'name': 'Peter', 'category_id': '25', 'level': 'advanced'}, 
{'id': '3', 'name': 'Toni', 'category_id': '20', 'level': 'beginner'}])
```

Comment: Any effort from your side? What have you tried so far? SO is not a coding service. As a starting point why dont you loop over the second dictionary

Comment: Your description is a little confusing. You don't have two dictionaries: you have two lists of dictionaries. However, you could make you code more efficient by building a dictionary from `categories`, with the category_id value as the key, and the associated level as the value.

Comment: Your data is far from optimally structured for the transformation you want to achieve, so you should think about what structure would make the problem easier, then try to transform your existing structure.

Comment: @Marvin Taschenberger, see EDIT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a mapping from `category_id` to additional field(s), then combine the dictionaries in a loop, e.g:

```
cat = {d["category_id"]: d for d in categories}
res = []

for name in names:
    x = name.copy()
    x.update(cat[name["category_id"]])  
    res.append(x)
```

In Python 3.5+ you can use the cool new syntax:

```
cat = {d["category_id"]: d for d in categories}
res = [{**name, **cat[name["category_id"]]} for name in names]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider what you really want to do: add the level associated with each category to the `names` dict. So first, create a mapping from the categories to the associated levels:

```
cat_dict = {d['category_id']: d['level'] for d in categories}
```

It's then a trivial transformation on each dict in the `names` list:

```
for d in names:
    d['level'] = cat_dict[d['category_id']]
```

The resulting `names` list is:

```
[{'category_id': '25', 'id': '1', 'level': 'advanced', 'name': 'Peter'},
 {'category_id': '20', 'id': '2', 'level': 'beginner', 'name': 'Jim'},
 {'category_id': '20', 'id': '3', 'level': 'beginner', 'name': 'Toni'}]
```